# Sufficient condition for a.s. convergence

Tags: probability-theory

I'm reading Shiryaev's "[Probability](https://books.google.ca/books/about/Probability_1.html?id=WTGmDAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)" book. In Chapter 10 the author states the following result:

[image]

It seems that the first equality is not correct because 
$$
\bigcup_{k\ge n}\{|\xi_k-\xi|\ge \varepsilon\}\subseteq\{\sup_{k\ge n}|\xi_k-\xi|\ge \varepsilon\}.
$$
The result, however, remains true if we replace the first "$\ge$" with strict inequality, i.e. for any $\eta<\varepsilon$
\begin{align*}
\mathsf{P}\left\{\sup_{k\ge n}|\xi_k-\xi|\ge \varepsilon\right\}&\le \mathsf{P}\left\{\sup_{k\ge n}|\xi_k-\xi|> \eta\right\} \\
&\le \mathsf{P}\left\{\bigcup_{k\ge n}|\xi_k-\xi|\ge \eta\right\} \\
&\le \sum_{k\ge n}\mathsf{P}\{|\xi_k-\xi|\ge \eta\}.
\end{align*}

Am I missing something?

Comment: You are right about that; just consider for instance $\xi_k := 1-\frac{1}{k}$, $\xi := 0$ and $\epsilon=1$.

Comment: @saz Sure. But does the correction work? I mean that $(8)$ is sufficient anyway...

Comment: Yeah, with "$>$" everything works fine.